# Fill in a table name using a variable from another query

Tags: postgresql, dynamic-sql

I have a general query I need to run for many tables

```
SELECT sum(honoraria_amount)
FROM table_1
```

The table IDs I have a list, from another query. For example, I want to run this for: `table_1`, `table_39`, `table_42`, etc.

Since I have a query that returns the IDs:

```
table_id
----
1
39
42
```

Is there anyway I can feed these query results, into the `sum` query, like some form of replacing with a variable or array to iterate through?

If its possible I'd like to replace `x` below with the IDs and maybe loop through all the queries to print out all the sums:

```
SELECT sum(honoraria_amount)
FROM table_x
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12777231/string-substitution-with-query-result-postgresql/12777516#12777516

Answer (score 1):

Normally I'd advise against dynamic SQL as it can't be cached by the engine, but I don't see any other alternative that doesn't add a hurdle every time you wish to add a new one of these table_x's.

With that in mind, the following function will help you out:

```
create or replace function sum_table(
    tid integer
) returns numeric as $$
declare
    _out numeric;
begin
    execute 'select sum(honoraria_amount) from table_' || tid::text || ';' into _out;
    return _out;
end;
$$ language plpgsql;
```

And then to use it in a query:

```
with
    __tables as(
        select unnest(array[1, 39, 42]) as table_id
    )
select
    table_id,
    sum_table(table_id)
from
    __tables
```

Answer (score 0):

Would it be acceptable for you to build a view with `UNION ALL` over all the tables and then make your select on this view? Like

```
CREATE VIEW union_table (id, name)
  AS      ( SELECT honoraria_amount,... FROM foreign_table_1 UNION ALL 
            SELECT honoraria_amount, ... FROM foreign_table_2 
  ) ;
```